# How to use multiple TextInput for validation without using any outside 3rd party packages in React Native

Tags: validation, react-native, textinput

I am having a login and signup form in my app for which I need to do input fields validation. 
I am beginner to React-Native app development.

I have tried some packages:
**reference:**

1. https://github.com/NewOldMax/react-native-validator-form
2. https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-textfield

essential package versions I am using for my app:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

but I am having little difficulties in working with them. So I need to handle validations from my app side in react-native only. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: you can use state for that like store each value in different state variable and you can check that state value before onSubmit api call

Comment: @PrakashKarena thanks I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

create your own validation checking

onChangeText or onSubmit check the error through validators. [here](https://gist.github.com/AurangzaibRamzan/b78ebc4cc3ae3d9840c894f25ad1157b) is helper funtions that I have use in my application.

Answer (score 1):

you can use RegEx patterns/rules to validate TextInputs

there is a medium article  https://medium.com/@react.ui.kit/react-native-textinput-validation-using-regex-patterns-rules-d811e8eee9aa